# Probabilistically Sample from an Array in Perl

Tags: r, algorithm, perl, probability

I have an array in Perl and I would like to draw samples from it in a probabilistic manner. For example in `R` the function `sample` does it for me, e.g.

```
x = c('a','b','c','d')
sample(x,size = 2,prob = c(0.1,0.4,0.4,0.1))
```

The above code would return `b,c` more often. How do I do the same in Perl. Is there a module that does it for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would work, but I need to do this at scale. I read through the module's notes on CPAN, it sends an inter-process signal to an R interpreter, which is bound to be slow

Comment: Perhaps https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util::WeightedChoice

Comment: Sample a vector such as `unlist(mapply(rep, x, prob/min(prob)))` or `c("a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be done in [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL) (at scale) using the vsearch function.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;

my @x = qw( a b c d );

my $pdf = pdl( 0.1, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1 );

# vsearch requires a CDF,
my $cdf = $pdf->dcumusumover;
$cdf /= $cdf->max;

# $sample is a piddle containing the indices into @x;
my $sample = vsearch( random(10000), $cdf );

print scalar hist( $sample, 0, 4, 1 ), "\n";
```

results in

```
% perl x.pl
[991 3974 4014 1021]
```

Answer (score 0):

With basic perl commands you could just do something like

```
my @vals = ('a','b','c','d');
my @probs = (0.1,0.4,0.4,0.1);
my @result;
for(my $i=0; $i<20; $i++) {
    my $draw = rand(1);
    my $v = 0;
    while ($draw>0 && $draw > $probs[$v]){
        $draw -= $probs[$v];
        $v++;
    }
    push @result, $vals[$v];
}

print join(", ", @result), "\n";
```

Comment: For larger sized arrays this will be rather slow. It'll be more efficient to generate a cumulative sum of the probabilities and use a binary search (e.g. [List::Binary::Search](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::BinarySearch)) to calculate the indices.

Comment: The `fo`r loop in your code can be made more efficient: change it to `for (0..19)`

Comment: I'm not sure the generated result will necessarily follow the proposed distribution of 0.1,0.4,0.4,0.1

Comment: @broccoli Is there a reason you think that?